# Java task queue, threadpool and threads with callback to inform when a new task can start

Tags: java, multithreading, callback, threadpool

I have tried to find a way how to load several web pages in multiple threads with a certain maximum limit of threads, in a way such that a new page is loaded when one finish. There should also be another post-processing threads for the loaded content after the page is downloaded so that the whole process is chained.

How I'd like to make it:

- Task queue holds the pages that should be downloaded
- Threadpool has a certain number of threads downloading the pages in the task queue (loading the pages take some time so the number of
  threads can be much higher than the number of the cpu cores)
- When a page's download is completed, the thread should notify this so that a new task from the queue can be started instead
- When a page's download is completed, the content should be transferred to another task queue for the post-processing
- Another threadpool has as many threads as the cpu has cores (guess it is fastest to have only one thread per core for the post-processing), this threadpool perform post-processing on the downloaded pages.
- When a page's post-processing is completed, the thread should notify it so that another page in the queue can be post-processed
- When all pages has been downloaded (the queue is empty), the first threadpool can be shutdown, the other threadpool can be shutdown when both task queues are empty (all pages has been downloaded and post-processed)

I have something like:

```
            for (int j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
            threads[j].start();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < threads.length; j++) {
            threads[j].join();
        }
```

But this way all pages to load are in separate threads at the same time and I want to limit the number of threads. More importantly I want to reuse the threads and make a thread do the next task when one task is finished. I could do that with a while loop, but this is what I'm trying to avoid, I don't want a while loop to check if the queue has more tasks and if a thread is free. Is it possible to use some kind of callback, so that the thread tells back to the pool that is is completed and returns the data.
I also want the downloading tasks to ~store the content in a data structure and add it futher to the post-processing task queue.

The best resources I found so far is:
[Thread pools](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-pools.html)
[Callback](https://coderanch.com/t/389877/java/java-callback)

But I don't know if it even is possible to create it the way I want. I' stuck in thinking about function pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use low-level thread methods to do that. Have a `downloadExecutor` thread pool, and submit `DownloadTask` instances (implementing `Runnable` or `Callable`) to this pool.

At the end of the DownloadTask's code, submit the a PostProcessPageTask instance (once again implementing implementing `Runnable` or `Callable`) to a second `postProcessExecutor` thread pool.

You could use one or two CountDownLatch instances that every task would decrement when finished, and have the main thread awaiting on this (or these) latches to know when the thread pools must be shut down.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html and docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html for more information.

Comment: Is there any point in using two pools?  Why not just download and process in one task class on one pool.  I don't see any advantage in queueing the downloaded data to another pool that's using the same processor cores.

Comment: I'll look into that JB and get back to you later, I think having the DownloadTask to submit a PostProcessPageTask to the second executor will do just what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Martin:
I could even do everything in serial and not parallel at all, but my intention was to try make it faster. Downloading the content from a page depends mostly on the transfer speed (as long there's not too much other load on the cpu), therefore I can download many pages at the same time, but post processing of the content depends only on the cpu load. Therefore if let's say I download content from 100 pages at a time, I will have around 100 threads doing the post-processing too, but that would not be efficient as it is faster to have fewer threads completing the work faster instead.

Comment: @user979899 certainly, a pool of threads is going to be much, much faster than serial downloading, (if only from mitigating network latency).  Whether using two pools is worth it, I'm not so convinced.  Maybe you could try both, just as an experiment?  You have to write all the gungy network and processing methods anyway, so trying one or two pools would just be moving some commenting-out around?  I'm just curious..

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, i think it would be an interesting experiment. It will probably depend on the transfer speed, the web pages size, number of threads in both pools and other load on the cpu at the moment. If there are too many threads in use, the cpu will become the bottleneck and not the transfer speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guava's [ListenableFutures](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html).

First you need to submit download tasks to the [ListenableExecutorService](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService.html), then transform resulting futures with post processor via [Futures.transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html).

```
ListenableExecutorService dlPool = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(firstPool);
ListenableExecutorService procPool = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(secondPool);

List<ListenableFuture<Result>> results = new ArrayList<...>();
for (String url : urls) {
  // download task
  ListenableFuture<String> html = dlPool.submit(...);
  // post process
  ListenableFuture<Result> result = Futures.transform(html,
    new Function<String, Result>() {
      ... // post process
    }, procPool);
  results.add(result);
}

// blocks until all results are processed
List<Result> processed = Futures.allAsList(results).get();

firstPool.shutdownNow();
secondPool.shutdownNow();
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to code up this type of general infrastructure by hand.

Java 5 and above ships with the lovely java.util.concurrent package

It should be the first thing you turn to when making multithreaded applications.

It has lots of general tools like threadpools (which execute Runnable or Callable objects) and will do a lot of the dog-work for you.

There are loads of great free resources about it on the Internet, or if you prefer books, Brian Goetz's "Java Concurrency in Practice" is widely considered to be one of the best.